# Detect when a variable is a certain value in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am working on an inactivity timeout for my app.  When inactivity is detected, a modal is launched.  The modal displays a timer to the user.  When the timer (which is a counter) hits 0, I want to be able to "know" the counter is 0 so I can implement the logic to sign-off the user.

```
export class IdleModalComponent implements OnInit {

counter$: Observable<number>;   
count = 300 // 5 minutes for the user to respond before we implement the inactivity logic

constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<IdleModalComponent>) {
        this.counter$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        take(this.count), 
        map(() => (--this.count)), 
    );
  }
}
```

When I bind the counter observable in the HTML, it accurately displays the countdown.  All I need is to be able to capture when:

`this.count === 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tap` **rxjs** operator without **directly subscribing** like the following :

```
this.counter$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(this.count),
  map(() => (--this.count)),
  tap(val => {
    if (val === 0) {
      // do what you want such as show modal
      alert('The count is 0');
    }
  })
)
```

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rubvcq)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  As an Angular dev for over a year, sometimes I feel so silly when I don't know simple rxjs operators...

Answer (score 2):

Timer [emit numbers in sequence every specified duration.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer#after-given-duration-emit-numbers-in-sequence-every-specified-duration).

To use map function idiomatically, do not cause any side effects in it, just map the received value.

Finally, to observe the completion:

- Subscribe to the observable
- pass in complete callback

```
const initialCounter = 10;

timer(0, 100)
  .pipe(
    take(initialCounter),
    map(v => initialCounter-v))
  .subscribe({
    next: v => console.log(v),
    complete: () => console.log('finished')
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's when the `this.counter$` is completed.

```js
this.counter$
  .subscribe(
    () => {}, // each time of count update
    () => {}, // error
    () => {
       // completed and `this.count === 0`
    }
  )
```

**Working Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-timer-complete?file=src/app/app.component.ts